# mutiValueDictKeyError in django

Tags: django

I am a novice in the Django app development. I was trying to develop a simple app where it adds two numbers. I am getting MulitValuedDictKeyError. I referred to a few questions of the same type previously asked and tried some solutions, but none worked. Kindly help me fix it.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html',{'name':'pavan sunder'})

def add(request):
    val1 = request.GET["num1"]
    val2 = request.GET["num2"]
    res = val1 + val2
    return render(request, 'result.html',{'result':res})
```

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>hello {{name}}</h1>

<form action="add">
    Enter 1st number:<input type="text",name="num1"><br>
    Enter 2nd number:<input type="text",name="num2"><br>
    <input type="Submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

**result.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
Result:{{result}}
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

error msg:

> MultiValueDictKeyError at /add
>   'num1'
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/add
>   Django Version: 2.2.6
>   Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
>   Exception Value:
>   'num1'
>   Exception Location: C:\Users\PAVANM~1\django\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py in **getitem**, line 80
>   Python Executable:  C:\Users\PAVANM~1\django\Scripts\python.exe
>   Python Version: 3.7.1
>   Python Path:
>   ['C:\Users\pavan m sunder\projects\django\tst',
>    'C:\Users\PAVANM~1\django\Scripts\python37.zip',
>    'C:\Users\PAVANM~1\django\DLLs',
>    'C:\Users\PAVANM~1\django\lib',
>    'C:\Users\PAVANM~1\django\Scripts',
>    'c:\users\pavan m '
>    'sunder\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib',
>    'c:\users\pavan m '
>    'sunder\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs',
>    'C:\Users\PAVANM~1\django',
>    'C:\Users\PAVANM~1\django\lib\site-packages']
>   Server time:    Wed, 23 Oct 2019 05:32:02 +0000

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<form action="add">
```

To:

```
<form action="{% url 'add' %}" method="get">
```

---

Change:

```
val1 = request.GET["num1"]
val2 = request.GET["num2"]
```

To:

```
val1 = int(request.GET["num1"])
val2 = int(request.GET["num2"])
```

---

Change:

```
<input type="text",name="num1"><br>
```

To:

```
<input type="text" name="num1"><br>
```

No need of `,`.

Comment: that comma was a problem i think

Comment: @Pavan Did it work? If yes, then feel free to mark it as accepted, so that it can be helpful to others in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because your running this url ***http://127.0.0.1:8000/add*** first and no values were filled in the form.

Run  *http://127.0.0.1:8000* which is the home page and enter the two numbers,then press **submit** button, that will work if the code contain no anyother error.

Hope it's not to late to reply